# Having a footer that is always on bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that this might be a trivial problem but I'm having some problems. In my main.html I have 3 divs where 1st one contains the navbar, the 2nd is an "empty" div that loads stuff from other html-files with JQuery/Javascript. The 3rd one is the footer.

I'm trying to implement a footer that is always on the bottom of the page (the way you only see it when you've scrolled to the bottom of the page) but here's the thing. My 2nd div loads stuff without refreshing the page so when it loads a html-file that is "longer" the previous one, the footer stays right in the content. How can I fix that?

Hope you guys understand!

TLDR: Footer stays right on div 2 if the div loads stuff bigger than the previous one.
Structure is like this:
2nd div:

```
<div id="background-block">
    <div id="text-block">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

3rd div:

```
<div id="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
    <!-- content -->
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: `#footer { position: fixed; bottom: 0; }`

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS to fixed your footer at bottom

```
.footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried with fixed but I don't want it always at the bottom of the page, only when you've scrolled down, sorry if i wrote bad on my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Think this is referred to as a "sticky footer". A quick google search turns up a load of articles.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CSS position: fixed

Answer (score 1):

**using style**   `Position:fixed;bottom: 0;`

**Always Fix In bottom**

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.content{

}
.header{
   border:1px solid black;
}
.MiddleContent{
    border:1px solid black;
}
.footer{
    border:1px solid black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    Color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="header">
 <h2>
 Header
 </h2>
</div>
<div class="MiddleContent">
 <h2>
 Middle Content
 
 </h2>
 hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>
</div>
<div class="footer">
Footer
</div>


</div>
```

**using** `position: absolute;` then scroll then footer will not fixed and move with scroll

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.content{

}
.header{
   border:1px solid black;
}
.MiddleContent{
    border:1px solid black;
}
.footer{
    border:1px solid black;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    Color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
<div class="header">
 <h2>
 Header
 </h2>
</div>
<div class="MiddleContent">
 <h2>
 Middle Content
 
 </h2>
 hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>hello <br>
</div>
<div class="footer">
Footer
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, just upated my op. I want the footer to always be on the bottom of the page (after scrolling) so not really always visible like you showed. Thanks though :/

Comment: i updated my answer .base your requirement footer will not fixed but you can scroll then footer will be move.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the second markup sample, here is a CSS-only solution that should work:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}

.footer {
    position: relative;
    max-width:13.66rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5.6rem 0;
}
```